# Screen.width seems to be strafing from the center of the screen instead of relative to the screen size on full screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, screen

I have a C# script controlling my main camera on my top down perspective of a tower defense game I'm working on. To my knowledge, Screen.width is supposed to scale with screen size so using Screen.width - desired border thickness as a qualifier for camera movement should trigger from the specified location at the border thickness's edge of the screen in the qualifying direction.

The problem I'm having is that regardless of screen size, bringing the mouse over the middle point of the screen to the right causes the camera to shift that direction. This is exclusive to strafing right - left behaves as intended with the same code.

What I'm guessing is that the left side works because the screen pixel count starts from the lower left, and for some reason Screen.width is constraining it's scaling to be relative to Screen.height, but I'm unable to find anyone else really running into the same problem on a 3d project which makes me think I'm overlooking something silly. I saw something about orthographic camera applying to 2d projects but figured I'd shoot something here in case someone knew off the top of their head what was up.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool doMovement = true;

    public float panSpeed = 20f;
    public float panBorderThickness = 10f;

    public float scrollSpeed = 5f;
    public float minY = 40f;
    public float maxY = 120f;


    void Update () {

        if (GameManager.gameIsOver)
        {
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            doMovement = !doMovement;

        if (!doMovement)
            return;

        if (Input.GetKey("d") || Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.height - panBorderThickness)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.mousePosition.x <= panBorderThickness)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.back * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s") || Input.mousePosition.y <= panBorderThickness)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("w") || Input.mousePosition.y >= Screen.width - panBorderThickness)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }

        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        Vector3 pos = transform.position;

        pos.y -= scroll * 1000 * scrollSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, minY, maxY);

        transform.position = pos;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

Screen.height-Input.mousePosition.y

the y in screen position and input are opposite, its not your left right its your up down.